# Divergence of a Vector field in Einstein soliton

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, divergence-theorem

An $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is an Einstein soliton if there exist a vector field $\zeta$ and a real constant $\lambda$ such that
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ric}{Ric} \DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}$
$$
\Ric+\frac{1}{2}L_\zeta g=\lambda g +\frac{r}{2}g,
$$
where $L_{\zeta}$ stands for the Lie derivative operator in the direction of $\zeta$, $\Ric$ is the Ricci curvature and $r$ is the scalar curvature of $g$.

Denote by $\eta=i_\zeta g$ the dual $1$-form of $\zeta$ and define the $(1, 1)$-tensor field $F$ by
$$
g(FX,Y):=\frac{1}{2}d\eta(X,Y),
$$
for any $X,Y$ smooth vector fields of $M$.

Then how we obtain following two identities from above equations:
$$
\nabla\zeta=F-Q +\left(\lambda  +\frac{r}{2}\right)I,
$$
where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection of $g$, $Q$ is the Ricci operator defined by $g(QX, Y) := \Ric(X, Y)$, for $X, Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ and $I$ is the identity endomorphism on the set of vector fields on $M$.

And the second one is
\begin{align}
\Div(\zeta)&=\frac{2n\lambda+(n-2)r}{2} \\
\Div(F\zeta)&=-\|F\|-\sum_{i=1}^ng((\nabla_{E_i}F)E_i,\zeta)
\end{align}

Comment: Hint for the first identity: $L_{X}g = 2g(\nabla_{.} X,\cdot)$ for any vector field $X$. Apply this for $X = \zeta$.

Comment: The second identity is obtained by tracing the first one.

Comment: How do you guys even manage to understand these equalities? :-/. I wish to understand them. :-/

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto well, one has to understand what each object present in the equalities represent. What is the Ricci tensor? It is a bilinear map that takes pairs of smooth vector fields on a given manifold and outputs a real smooth function. How does it come to be? From the Riemannian metric. What is a Riemannian metric? What are smooth vector fields? What does it mean to smoothly take pairs of smooth vector fields and output a real smooth function, how does one define smoothness in this context? What is the divergence of a tensor? Well, it is another tensor defined using the covariant derivati+

Comment: ve... What is the covariant derivative of a tensor? Well, it is defined using the Levi-Civita connection. How does the Levi-Civita connection come to be? And so on, and so on...

Comment: I managed to prove all the equalities except the last one, referring to $\operatorname{div}(F \zeta)$. They're straightforward, just use the definition of the Lie derivative, the explicit formula for the exterior derivative of a $1$-form, and the fact that we're using the Riemannian connection (which is, in particular, symmetric). I think there might be something wrong with the $\| F \|$ term. Could you tell us where you saw these identities?

Comment: For proving identities we can use $div X = \frac{1}{2}tr_g(L_X g)$ and suggested by Didier. @MatheusAndrade These identies are from a research article from Blaga and Deshmukh named "Einstein solitons with unit geodesic potential vector field".

Comment: @user1911221 I am not familiar to notation $E_i$ or why is $div(X)$ given by formula as you provide. May you clarify it please?

Comment: $\{E_i\}_{1\leq i\leq n}$ a local orthonormal frame field on $(M,g).$ @BrunoPeixoto

Comment: Ooh, nice. Like "Given covering atlas $M$ of Riemannian manifold $(\mathcal{M}, g)$ composed of charts $\{(U_i, \phi_i)\}$, the orthonormal frame field $\{E_j\}_i$ is given by push forward vectors $\{{\phi_i}_* \partial_j\}$"?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto not exactly, although you've got the right ideas in mind. Assuming in your definition of charts they go from the manifold to Euclidean space, the pushforward vectors you mention are just Euclidean vectors. Given a point $p \in M$ and a chart $\varphi: U \ni p \to \mathbb{R}^n$, an orthonormal frame field at $q \in U$ can be obtained by applying the Gram-Schmidt process to the vectors $$\left\{ \mathrm{d} \left(\varphi^{-1}\right)_q \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r^i} \right|_{\varphi(q)}\right) \right\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$$

Comment: Well, this is the definition of pullpack $\varphi^* \partial_i$ as far as I know.